# How to get name and phonenumber peoplePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

So i am trying to follow the guides and tutorials that apple gives about the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

So far what i have been able to do is to get the picker to show and see all the avaliable contacts using this code:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
        [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

And then to display the information i use the code provided by apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html

If you scroll down a bit and see **Listing 1-4  Displaying a person’s information**.

Im using that code but it never runs.

All i can do is get the picker working. Select a person and see its information.

What i want to do is. After a person is clicked then ONLY the number/s will show and i will be able to click it to use it in code. How can i do this?

I am using my cellphone to post this question so please be gentle :P.

Comment: Did you add `<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>`?

Comment: Yes i did @cojoj , what i noticed is that when i was going to write the method for displayPerson it did not find it i had to manually write it. Is it suppsed to be one of the delagate methods?

Comment: It is an instance method, you might need to implement it in .`m` file. Just check carefully on the tutorials.

Comment: `displayPerson:` isn't a delegate method. It's a method implemented in your controller to display this `Person` object on view.

Comment: This thread may contain the answer for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806774/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-changes-with-ios8

Comment: But does that code do what i want it to do? I only want the phone number/s to show