# Contacts Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, contacts

first of all i'm trying to make a view controller who shows all of you contacts on your phone and you can add a contact ! (see picture) https://i.stack.imgur.com/0twxS.png

i know i have to ask from the user if "my app" could get acces to the users contacts !

can someone show me how to this ? 
how can i get ask for acces to the users contacts and how can i load the contacts (exact like the apple general contact app on iOS devices) in a view controller and how can i add a contact to the contacts on you phone

has someone a tutorial or something ? 
language : swift

thnx regards Quinn

Comment: try using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806774/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-changes-with-ios8

Comment: Try looking at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/97936/address-book-tutorial-swift-ios

Comment: hi, this question (while valid) is a bad fit for Stackoverflow as it is WAY too broad. Find a tutorial/book and come back if you have specific issues